# How to approach accessing large amounts of data using javascript

Tags: javascript, web

I'm working on a personal web project to create a practice test website for students at my university. I have a list of a bunch of words (100+) with their definitions, word families and whatnot. Currently I have the entire list copy and pasted directly into the javascript code (I know, I'm so sorry) but this is gross and I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Can I draw the data from a text file, or perhaps a database using javascript? I'm rather new to web development (in terms of structure) and was wondering if I could get some direction. I am using CPanel currently running on my school's server with my student account. I have access to MySQL databases and the whole suite of tools.

Thank you!

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to put the data inside a json file on the server and then load the data with javascript into the site. So you have a clean separation of code and data. But it depends what future plans you have for the website. Do you have plans to create user accounts and so on?

Comment: You want JSON for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Thank you guys! I will look into JSON. @ChiefWiggum yes I am planning to add user accounts later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the size of this words object. If your list of words is not that heavy, you can simply store in a JSON file. This would a very raw solution.
Or you can create tables in MySQL and use a suitable programming language like Java Python etc to interface with the database and send the response ahead.
If you have a lot of data and a lot of operations under the hood on that data, I would suggest you optimize your approach and get data in Chunks using AJAX.

Another approach is store a certain amount of data in a Web worker so you can provide a chunk of that data directly from there avoiding a network call. Either way its the same thing.Fetch new data as and when required and store it in your web worker by clearing the previous stale data.

Comment: Since the list shouldn't be too heavy, I will look into JSON. Thank you!